# PreexistingEntityException error in NetBeans

Tags: java, database, compiler-errors, netbeans-8.2

I am trying to create a Java application using Netbeans 8.2 for a uni project. I'm having an issue after creating a `JFrame` for adding some data to the database.

NetBeans highlights the final statement `ujc.create(u2);` in the code segment below with the following error message:

```
Unreported exception PreexistingEntityException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Can someone advise what I need to do to fix this issue? I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
   private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
   {
      Users u2 = new Users();
      u2.setEmployeeno(jTextField1.getText());
      u2.setFirstname(jTextField2.getText());
      u2.setSurname(jTextField3.getText());
      
      EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
              "BatteryManagementSystemPU");
      UsersJpaController ujc = new UsersJpaController(emf);
      ujc.create(u2);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `create(...)` method call here can fail, so we need to allow for that failure by surrounding the method with a try/catch block:

```
try
{
    ujc.create(u2);
}
catch(PreexistingEntityException e)
{
    System.err.println("Caught PreexistingEntityException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You can find great information on the topic at the official tutorial page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

The other option is to throw the error, however, the calling method for `jButton1ActionPerformed` will now need to catch the error instead, so it's better not to use this solution in most cases if you are unsure on what is happening:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws PreexistingEntityException
{
    ....
```

You can find more information on throwing an error here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have worked. What was confusing me was that I built a project that was more or less exactly the same however it never threw up that error message.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the difference is. Either you called a method that didn't need to catch/throw an error, or as a guess you may have hit Alt+Enter in Netbeans by mistake and it could have added the `throws PreexistingEntityException` to the main method etc, and assuming an error is never encountered the code would work as expected.